# How to add a search based multivalued parameter in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report that has 10 thousand records in a filter(parameter not the SSRS filter) which is in multivalued parameter. So, locating the values in the dropdown of the parameter is much harder. I need to add a search based multivalued parameter in the report to make filter easy. Please guide me to do that or text me any other possible suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using two parameters.

Let's say you had a big list of customer names.

In your first parameter (let's call is `cSearch`) this is just a plain text parameter NOT multi-value.

In your second parameter use a dataset query something like

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName 
    FROM myCustomers
    WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%' + @cSearch + '%'
```

Once your first parameter is filled in, when you click the second it will be populated only with matching values.

---

Edit with more detailed explaination

---

To expand on this I put together a very quick report to show what I mean. If this is not what you intended, then please edit your question add as much detail as you can, screen shots of the design, a mock-up of what you expect to see, all the permutations of parameter states etc.

I used the Adventure Work LT sample data for this in case you want to follow it.

Create a new report

Create a new dataset (as datasource if required)

Set the query for the dataset to be

```
  SELECT  CustomerID, CompanyName 
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[SalesLT].[Customer] 
WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%' + @cSearch + '%'
ORDER by CompanyName
```

When you add the dataset, a new report parameter will be generated called `cSearch` .

Go to this parameter's properties and do the following

set the `Allow blank value ("")` on
set the default value to an expression `=""`

This will set the parameter to be an empty string when the report first runs.

Next, add another parameter called `pCustomers'

Set this to "Allow multiple values"

Set the Available values to your dataset, select `CustomerID` as the Value field and CompanyName as the Label field.

Next set Default Values to the same dataset and again choose the CustomerID as the Value field.

Now, when you first run the report, the `cSearch` parameter is empty so all Company Names are listed in your second parameter.

[image]

If we then type "world" into the search parameter and press enter, the second parameter values are updated...

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alan, Can you please explain what I can do using SSRS? I have used it but both fields are mandatory, sometimes user doesn't fill the plain text parameter. And I have other parameters that values are also consider for this parameter. When I use OR for cSearch, dropdown is not showing correct values.

Comment: I'll try to post an exmaple later, I'm working 16 hour days at the moment so might not get time

Comment: Okay @Alan. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Alan for gave me an best alternative solution. But SSRS should include search based multivalued parameter like PowerBI in future. Thanks