# SSRS Search Multi-Select Parameter using Text Paramater where the resulting items in Multi-select list are filterable

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, string-search

I've create two parameters p_search and p_destination. Have two datasets, main data set and destination dataset.

The Main Dataset query to pull all data for report has this where clause:
where destination IN(@p_destination)

The p_search parameter is just a text box that allows blank values.

The p_destination parameter is a multi-value list box that uses the following dataset where clause.
where destinationname Like '%' + @p_search + '%'.

When I run the query, fill in the p_search text box and hit tab,  the results in the multi-select drop down are correct.

Then I select a few of the values in the The results list and hit run report.

The report run results instead of showing the specific ones selected in the multi-select dropdown, show all of the search results.

Solution suggestions. I used this solution by Alan Schofield to get this far:
[How to add a search based multivalued parameter in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646274/how-to-add-a-search-based-multivalued-parameter-in-ssrs)

Main Dataset Query:

```
 -------------------4B--------------------
     SELECT tp.[Constituent ID]
     ,tp.[Preferred Name]
     ,tp.[Last Name]
     ,tp.[First Name]
     ,tp.[Constituent Preferred Class Year]
     ,tc.[Contribution ID]
    ,tc.ContNumSort
    ,tc.[Contribution Date]
  ,tc.elcn_contributiontype
  ,tc.ConTypeName
  ,tc.elcn_solicitationmethodid
  ,tc.[Solicitation Method]
  ,tc.[Destination ID]
  ,tc.Destination
  ,tc.[Campaign ID]
  ,tc.Campaign
  FROM #temp_contributions tc LEFT JOIN  #temp_porgs tp  ON 
  Tc.PERORGID=tp.PerOrgID
  WHERE tc.statuscode=1
  AND tc.destination IN(@p_destination)
order by tp.[Full Name], tc.ContNumSort
```

The @p_destination parameter dataset

```
Select elcn_destinationid, Elcn_destination
FROM elcn_destination
WHERE elcn_destination LIKE '%' + @p_search + '%'
```

Comment: The issue is that your parameter is adding the % to the whole parameter string and not each individual selection. `WHERE destinationname Like '%red, blue%'` You really need a table of your parameters and JOIN the table on `LIKE '%' + Field + '%' `

Comment: @HannoverFist I think the question is worded badly, what the OP is trying to do is basically correct (I think)

Comment: @DoloresM Can you edit your question and show the exact dataset queries.

Comment: The key part here is the dataset query that returns data to the actual report, we need to see that query in full.

Comment: Everything appears to be correct. It would be interesting to see what values are being passed. Try adding a textbox somewhere to the report and set the expression as `=JOIN(Parameters!p_destination.Value, ", ")`. Then select 2 or 3 entries and view the report, you should see the 3 values in the textbox.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I fixed the issue. This part of the where clause was incorrect.  AND tc.destination IN(@p_destination) , tc.destination was not the unique id but the description. So once I changed it to the id it worked!